# How to deploy two services under two different applications in IIS using BTDF

Tags: deployment, msbuild, biztalk, msbuild-task, btdf

I have a requirement wherein I need to deploy two different services under two different application in IIS using BTDF.

`<IISMetabasePath>IIS://localhost/w3svc/1/Root</IISMetabasePath>`

using **IISMetabasePath** I can deploy multiple services but that will be deployed under same application/virtual directory in IIS, How can I make the IISMetabasePath parametric something like

`<IISMetabasePath>IIS://localhost/w3svc/{AppId}/Root</IISMetabasePath>`

so that I can specify the Id in **VDirList** configuration

Currently I have below **VDirList** config

```
<ItemGroup>
    <VDirList Include="*">
        <Vdir>GetCTCNumber</Vdir>
        <Physdir>..\CTCNumberService</Physdir>
        <AppPool>CTCNumberAppPool</AppPool>
        <AppPoolNetVersion>v4.0</AppPoolNetVersion>
    </VDirList>

    <VDirList Include="*">
        <Vdir>GetCTCusingTICCode</Vdir>
        <Physdir>..\TICCodeService</Physdir>
        <AppPool>TICCodeAppPool</AppPool>
        <AppPoolNetVersion>v4.0</AppPoolNetVersion>
    </VDirList>
</ItemGroup>
```

Appreciate the responses!

Thanks.

I have tried doing **IISMEtabasePath** parametric however I could not find the ways I could pass values to it from **VDirList**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VDirList functionality is deprecated and should not be used except for backwards compatibility. Instead, you should use IISApp and IISAppPool.

You didn't say which version of BTDF you are using, but you can refer to the IIS sample application that is included with the Framework. You'll also find IISApp/IISAppPool well-documented in the BTDF docs.

[Here's a link](https://github.com/BTDF/DeploymentFramework/releases/download/v5.7.0/DeploymentFrameworkForBizTalkDocsV5_7.pdf) to the v5.7 version of the docs in PDF format.